# overlapping dates between two date ranges in python

Tags: python, date, date-range

I'm looking to find overlapping dates between two dates ranges as the following:

```
range1 = start(2016-06-01) end (2016-06-20)
range2 = start(2016-06-10) end (2016-06-13)
```

result here is 4 dates `(2016-06-10,2016-06-11,2016-06-12,2016-06-13)`.
another example:

```
 range1 = start(2016-06-01) end (2016-06-20) range2 = start(2016-06-18)
 end (2016-06-25)
```

result here is 3 dates `(2016-06-18,2016-06-19,2016-06-20)`.
and if no dates overlap then the result is 0 dates.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044084/efficient-date-range-overlap-calculation-in-python) post its helpful in determining the number of overlapping dates but I was wondering if I can get the actual dates without using long if/else statements?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest generating the dates in each of both ranges, then selecting the intersection between the two set. A snipped doing so may look like this:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta


def f(d1, d2):
    delta = d2 - d1
    return set([d1 + timedelta(days=i) for i in range(delta.days + 1)])

range1 = [date(2016, 6, 1), date(2016, 6, 20)]
range2 = [date(2016, 6, 10), date(2016, 6, 13)]

print f(*range1) & f(*range2)
```

For performance purposes you can also cast `d1 + timedelta(days=i)` to `str` while generating the dates in a given range.

Comment: Thanks Kardaj! just wondering about the performance part, why casting to string will improve performance?

Comment: Because in the case that you're going to generate a lot of dates, you would prefer storing a less complex data-structure such as a string which for this case, won't lead to information loss.

Answer (score 2):

When you're not working with Python3 yet and thus cannot make use of the memory efficient `range` objects, you could make a namedtuple as shown in [the answer you link to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9044111/2476444) (otherwise you could just as well use the new `range` objects).
From there, all you need to do is use `datetime.date.fromordinal` on the overlapping daterange:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Range = namedtuple('Range', ['start', 'end'])
>>> r1 = Range(start=date(2016, 1, 1), end=date(2016, 2, 5))
>>> r2 = Range(start=date(2016, 1, 28), end=date(2016, 2, 28))
>>> latest_start = max(r1.start, r2.start)
>>> earliest_end = min(r1.end, r2.end)
>>> overlap = (earliest_end - latest_start).days + 1
>>> overlapping_dates = [] # default
>>> if overlap > 0:
...     overlapping_dates = range(latest_start.toordinal(), earliest_end.toordinal() + 1) # as numbers
...     overlapping_dates = [ date.fromordinal(x) for x in overlapping_dates ] # back to datetime.date objects
...
>>> overlapping_dates
[datetime.date(2016, 1, 28),
 datetime.date(2016, 1, 29),
 datetime.date(2016, 1, 30),
 datetime.date(2016, 1, 31),
 datetime.date(2016, 2, 1),
 datetime.date(2016, 2, 2),
 datetime.date(2016, 2, 3),
 datetime.date(2016, 2, 4),
 datetime.date(2016, 2, 5)]
```

An approach using `set` will work too (one of those approaches is in this answer's edit history), but is usually less efficient, because it has to have *all* dates in memory, even those that are not in the intersection.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small function for this recently, which returns whether there's an overlap and then the from-to range

```
def date_overlap(start1, end1, start2, end2):
    overlaps = start1 <= end2 and end1 >= start2
    if not overlaps:
        return False, None, None
    return True, max(start1, start2), min(end1, end2)
```

Obviously the output format can be adapted to whatever is needed.