# python time interval overlap duration

Tags: python, pandas, time, intervals, overlap

My question is similar to [Efficient date range overlap calculation in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044084/efficient-date-range-overlap-calculation-in-python), however, I need to calculate the overlap with a full timestamp and not days, but more importantly, I cannot specify a specific date as the overlap, rather only hours.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'first_ts': {0: np.datetime64('2020-01-25 07:30:25.435000'),
  1: np.datetime64('2020-01-25 07:25:00')},
 'last_ts': {0: np.datetime64('2020-01-25 07:30:25.718000'),
  1: np.datetime64('2020-01-25 07:25:00')}})
df['start_hour'] = 7
df['start_minute'] = 0
df['end_hour'] = 8
df['end_minute'] = 0
display(df)
```

How can I calculate the overlap duration of the interval (first_ts, last_ts) with the second interval in milliseconds?
Potentially, I would need to construct a timestamp on each day with the interval defined by the hours and then calculate the overlap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea is create new Series for start and end datetimes with dates by datetimes columns, use [`numpy.minimum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html) and [`numpy.maximum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html), subtract, convert timedeltas by [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) and multiple by `1000`:

```
s = (df['first_ts'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d ') + 
     df['start_hour'].astype(str) + ':' + 
     df['start_minute'].astype(str))
e = (df['last_ts'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d ') + 
     df['end_hour'].astype(str) + ':' +
     df['end_minute'].astype(str))

s = pd.to_datetime(s, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
e = pd.to_datetime(e, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

df['inter'] = ((np.minimum(e, df['last_ts']) - 
                np.maximum(s, df['first_ts'])).dt.total_seconds() * 1000)
print (df)
                 first_ts                 last_ts  start_hour  start_minute  \
0 2020-01-25 07:30:25.435 2020-01-25 07:30:25.718           7             0   
1 2020-01-25 07:25:00.000 2020-01-25 07:25:00.000           7             0   

   end_hour  end_minute  inter  
0         8           0  283.0  
1         8           0    0.0
```

Another idea is use only `np.minumum`:

```
df['inter'] = (np.minimum(df['last_ts'] - df['first_ts'], e - s).dt.total_seconds() * 1000)
print (df)
                 first_ts                 last_ts  start_hour  start_minute  \
0 2020-01-25 07:30:25.435 2020-01-25 07:30:25.718           7             0   
1 2020-01-25 07:25:00.000 2020-01-25 07:25:00.000           7             0   

   end_hour  end_minute  inter  
0         8           0  283.0  
1         8           0    0.0
```