# How to subset rows based on date overlap range efficiently using python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, date

My data frame has two date type columns: start and end (yyyy-mm-dd).

Here's my data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime 

data=[["2016-10-17","2017-03-08"],["2014-08-17","2016-09-08"],["2014-01-01","2015-01-01"],["2017-12-20","2019-01-01"]]

df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['start','end'])
df['start'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['start'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['end'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['end'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

       start        end
0 2016-10-17 2017-03-08
1 2014-08-17 2016-09-08
2 2014-01-01 2015-01-01
3 2017-12-20 2019-01-01
```

And I have reference start and end date as following.

```
ref_start=datetime.date(2015, 9, 20)
ref_end=datetime.date(2017,1,31)
print(ref_start,ref_end)
2015-09-20 2017-01-31
```

I would like to subset rows if the start and end date range of a row overlaps with **reference** start and end date. The third and the fourth rows are not selected since the start and end date range does not overlap with reference date range (2015-09-20 ~ 2017-01-31)

So my desired outcome looks like this:

```
        start         end
0  2016-10-17  2017-03-08
1  2014-08-17  2016-09-08
```

To do that, I was thinking about using the following codes based on this: [Efficient date range overlap calculation in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044084/efficient-date-range-overlap-calculation-in-python)

```
df[(max(df['start'],ref_start)>min(df['end'],ref_end))]
```

However, it doesn't work. Is there any way to get the desired outcome efficiently?

Answer (score 2):

A trick I learned early on in my career is what I call "crossing the dates": you compare the start of one range against the end of the other.

```py
# pd.Timestamp can do everything that datetime/date does and some more
ref_start = pd.Timestamp(2015, 9, 20)
ref_end = pd.Timestamp(2017,1,31)

# Compare the start of one range to the end of another and vice-versa
# Made into a separate variable for reability
cond = (ref_start <= df['end']) & (ref_end >= df['start'])
df[cond]
```