# Find common time in list of time ranges?

Tags: python, datetime

I have two lists:

```
lis1 = [(datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2, 9, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2, 9, 30)), (datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2, 11, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2, 12, 10))],
lis2 = [(datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2, 5, 9), datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2, 6, 56)), (datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2, 15, 37), datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2, 17, 24)),  (datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2, 9, 5), datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2, 9, 25))]
```

and I have a event duration of 10 minutes.
I want a common time range that resembles with both the list, meaning it should return a time which is available in both lists and is greater than the event duration for example in the above lists:
`datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2, 9, 5)` is the time which is available.
what i've tried

```
def compare_lists(list1, list2, duration):
    
    gap_list = []
    for x in list1:
        for y in list2:
            if x[0] < y[0] and y[0] < x[1] < y[1]:
                gap_list.append((y[0], x[1]))

            if y[0] < x[0] < y[1] and y[0] < x[1] < y[1]:
                gap_list.append((y[0], y[1]))

            if y[0] < x[0] < y[1] and y[1] > x[1]:
                gap_list.append((x[0], x[1]))

            if x[0] < y[0] < x[1] and x[0] < y[1] < x[1]:
                gap_list.append((y[0], y[1]))
                
    common_time = [t for t in gap_list if (t[1] - t[0]) > duration]
    return common_time


duration = timedelta(minutes=20)
ranges = [
    [(datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2, 9, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2, 9, 30)),(datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2, 11, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2, 12, 10))],
    [(datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2, 5, 9), datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2, 6, 56)), (datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2, 15, 37),datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2, 17, 24)),  (datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2, 15, 37), datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2, 9, 25))],
]

ret = compare_lists(ranges[0], ranges[1], duration)
print(ret)
```

the results is an empty list weather i have an common time or not.

Comment: i have tried alot of things, but right now, when its 15 minute left in deadline i think my brain stops working, can you plz atleast give me initiative, wdym by that stacks and events

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient date range overlap calculation in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044084/efficient-date-range-overlap-calculation-in-python)

Comment: @martineau see above edits sir