# How to avoid overlapping of dates in a mysql table

Tags: python, mysql, overlap

I am making a movie theatre management system in Python using mySQL and I need to make it so that if a datetime range is to be inserted such that it overlaps with another show that an error would be brought up.

For example, if I have a certain movie at 8PM in hall 1, and if i tried to insert another movie at the same time, an error would be brought up.

I have made a composite key between start time and hall that if there is an exact match in the newly inputed time and hall that an error is brought up. I have another column for the time when the movie ends and I would like to know how to make it possible that no other movie can be inserted between the start and end, for this certain hall.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swJZe.png)

This is the layout of the database

`cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO SHOWS(movie_name, showtimings,showend, hall, price, pricevip, pricevipb, priceprem) VALUES('{movname}', '{showtimings}','{endtime}', {hall}, {price}, {pricevip}, {pricevipb}, {priceprem})")`

Comment: You can refer to post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044084/efficient-date-range-overlap-calculation

Comment: MySQL have no RANGE datatype. You may solve your restriction with a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a 3-step process:

1. Identify available time slots based on current schedule
2. Check if the new schedule fits in available time slots
3. Insert the new schedule if a time slot available

First, simplify the schema and sample data to focus on the main question (note that reserved schedules are inserted if the hall if not available 24 hours a day):

```
create table shows (
    movie_name varchar(100),
    start_time timestamp,
    end_time timestamp,
    hall_id  int
);

insert into shows values ('@reserve#1', '2022-11-18 00:00:00', '2022-11-18 10:30:00', 1);
insert into shows values ('Spiderman' , '2022-11-18 11:00:00', '2022-11-18 14:00:00', 1);
insert into shows values ('Batman'    , '2022-11-18 15:00:00', '2022-11-18 17:00:00', 1);
insert into shows values ('Antman'    , '2022-11-18 17:00:00', '2022-11-18 19:30:00', 1);
insert into shows values ('@reserve#2', '2022-11-18 22:00:00', '2022-11-19 00:00:00', 1);
```

Second, check available slots with MySQL windows functions: (@show_start and @show_end is the new schedule)

```
set @show_start = '2022-11-18 14:00:00';
set @show_end   = '2022-11-18 14:30:00';

with cte_avail_slots as (
select hall_id,
       row_number() over (partition by hall_id order by start_time) as avail_slot,
       end_time as slot_start,
       lead(start_time,1) over (partition by hall_id order by start_time) as slot_end
  from shows)
select hall_id,
       avail_slot,
       slot_start,
       slot_end
  from cte_avail_slots
 where hall_id = 1
   and @show_start < @show_end
   and @show_start between slot_start and slot_end
   and @show_end   between slot_start and slot_end
;
```

Then, raise an error if no available slots; or insert the new schedule.