# Algorithm to discretize overlapping ranges

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I wrote a script to deal with overlapping intervals, I took several attempts at this before, I won't go into the details here, you can see [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/284913/234107) to get more context. This version is the smartest I came up with, it is the most efficient, and after rigorous testing I have determined that its output is completely correct.

The problem can be simplified as this, given a huge number of triples `(a, b, c)`, in each triple `a` and `b` are integers and `b >= a`, each triple represents a range `range(a, b + 1)`, and `c` is the data associated with the range. `(a, b, c)` is equivalent to `{range(a, b + 1): c}`.

There are a lot of overlaps in the ranges, and adjacent ranges that share data.

Suppose there are two such ranges, call them `(s0, e0, d0)` and `(s1, e1, d1)` respectively, one of the following 3 undesirable situations might happen:

- `s0 <= s1 <= e1 < e0`, the second range is completely contained within the first, and `d0 == d1`
- the second range is a sub range of the first, like above, but `d0 != d1`
- `e0 == s1 - 1 and d0 == d1`

The following situations never happen:

- `e0 == s1` and `s0 <= s1 and e0 <= e1`

The ranges either are completely discrete, or one is a complete subset of the other, there are no partial intersections.

Now I want to process the ranges such that there are no overlaps and all adjacent ranges share different data, this requires the following operations for each of the above 3 situations:

- ignore the subrange, do nothing, because they share the same data
- split the parent range, delete the overlapping portion of the parent range, and overwrite the overlapping range with the data of the sub range.
- ignore the second range, and set `e0` to `e1`, so that the two ranges are combined.

The result should contain no overlapping ranges and no extra ranges, each range has only one datum and it is always inherited from the newer, smaller range.

The input is sorted in such a way that can be obtained in Python by using `lambda x: (x[0], -x[1])` as key. And if the input is not sorted I will sort it in such a way before processing it.

This is a small example:

Data:

```
[(0, 10, 'A'), (0, 1, 'B'), (2, 5, 'C'), (3, 4, 'C'), (6, 7, 'C'), (8, 8, 'D')]
```

Meaning of the data:

```
[
    {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'A', 4: 'A', 5: 'A', 6: 'A', 7: 'A', 8: 'A', 9: 'A', 10: 'A'},
    {0: 'B', 1: 'B'},
    {2: 'C', 3: 'C', 4: 'C', 5: 'C'},
    {3: 'C', 4: 'C'},
    {6: 'C', 7: 'C'},
    {8: 'D'}
]
```

My intended process is equivalent to simply processing them in order and update the dictionary according to the current item one by one.

Processed data:

```
{0: 'B', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'C', 4: 'C', 5: 'C', 6: 'C', 7: 'C', 8: 'D', 9: 'A', 10: 'A'}
```

Output:

```
[(0, 1, 'B'), (2, 7, 'C'), (8, 8, 'D'), (9, 10, 'A')]
```

I need to do this as efficiently as possible, because I literally have millions of entries to process and that is not an exaggeration. I tried to use [`intervaltree`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/285124/234107) but it is way too inefficient for my purposes:

```
In [3]: %timeit merge_rows([[0, 10, 'A'], [0, 1, 'B'], [2, 5, 'C'], [3, 4, 'C'], [6, 7, 'C'],[8, 8, 'D']])
499 µs ± 14.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

---

### ***The following is my code***

```py
from bisect import bisect_left


class Interval:
    instances = []

    def __init__(self, start, end, data):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.data = data
        self.ends = [end]
        self.children = []
        Interval.instances.append(self)

    def variate(self, start, data):
        return not self.start <= start <= self.end or data != self.data

    def distinct(self, start, end, data):
        if self.end == start - 1 and self.data == data:
            self.ends[-1] = self.end = end
            return False
        return True

    def fill(self, start):
        if self.start < start:
            before = start - 1
            self.ends.insert(-1, before)
            self.children.append(Interval(self.start, before, self.data))

    def merge_worker(self, start, end, data):
        self.fill(start)
        add = self.start < start
        if not add:
            add = not self.children or self.children[-1].distinct(start, end, data)
        if add:
            self.children.append(Interval(start, end, data))
            self.ends.insert(-1, end)
        self.start = end + 1

    def merge(self, start, end, data):
        if not (self.variate(start, data) and self.distinct(start, end, data)):
            return
        if self.start <= start:
            self.merge_worker(start, end, data)
        else:
            self.children[bisect_left(self.ends, start)].merge(start, end, data)


def discretize(seq):
    Interval.instances.clear()
    current = -1e309
    for start, end, data in seq:
        if start > current + 1:
            top = Interval(start, end, data)
            current = end
        else:
            top.merge(start, end, data)
    return sorted(((i.start, i.end, i.data) for i in Interval.instances))
```

And it is much more efficient.

```
In [305]: %timeit discretize([[0, 10, 'A'], [0, 1, 'B'], [2, 5, 'C'], [3, 4, 'C'], [6, 7, 'C'],[8, 8, 'D']])
11 µs ± 85.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

I used the following code to test it:

[check.py (Google drive)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PIgF8L2-HGLCCZdQ4fM2HVZp3HKKe6Bi/view?usp=sharing)

English isn't my mother tongue and I am not really good at words so I won't describe my method, the code isn't hard to understand.

My question is, how can I dynamically calculate the insertion index of the so that I can insert the ranges in order directly, thus eliminating the need to sort the result? The result must be in order and sorting is really expensive.

I can attach an index to each instance when it is created but so far I only know how to use consecutive integers as index, just increment by one each time an instance is created, I don't know how to dynamically calculate the index required to make the instances keep sorted.

How can I calculate the index required? Or is there some better way?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044084/efficient-date-range-overlap-calculation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems like this are often solved with a [sweep line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm).

Imagine sweeping a vertical line along the x axis from -infinity to infinity.  As it meets the start or end of any interval, the "current data" may change.  All of these moments are "events", and by tracking the change of current data at each event, it's easy to calculate the output intervals.

For your problem, we can simply sort the intervals to get the sequence of start events.  At each start event, we can add the intervals that are starting to a collection of "current intervals".  The next end event is then the number after whichever of the current intervals ends first.  We can track this by keeping the current intervals in a priority queue.

Finally, note that if two intervals overlap, the one that ends first has priority, with the one that starts latest winning in case of a tie.  If we order our priority queue by (end, -start), then the first current interval gives us both the current data and the next end event.

Putting it all together, here's an implementation in python:

```py
import heapq

def descretize(intervals):
    if len(intervals) < 1:
        return []
    intervals = sorted(intervals)
    currentData = None
    out = []

    # read position in interval list
    inpos = 0

    # currently open output interval
    currentStart = None
    currentData = None

    # end events [(end_pos+1, -start_pos, data)]
    endq = []

    while inpos < len(intervals):

        # get the next event position
        evpos = intervals[inpos][0]
        if len(endq) > 0 and endq[0][0] < evpos:
            evpos = endq[0][0]
        
        # remove intervals that are no longer current
        while len(endq) > 0 and endq[0][0] <= evpos:
            heapq.heappop(endq)
        
        # add new current intervals
        while inpos < len(intervals) and intervals[inpos][0] <= evpos:
            s, e, data = intervals[inpos]
            inpos += 1
            heapq.heappush(endq,(e+1,-s,data))
        
        # get next current data
        nextData = endq[0][2] if len(endq) > 0 else None
        if nextData != currentData:
            # data changes here
            if currentData != None:
                out.append((currentStart, evpos-1, currentData))
            currentStart = evpos
            currentData = nextData

    # process remaining end events
    while len(endq) > 0:
        evpos = heapq.heappop(endq)[0]

        # remove intervals that are no longer current
        while len(endq) > 0 and endq[0][0] <= evpos:
            heapq.heappop(endq)

        # get next current data
        nextData = endq[0][2] if len(endq) > 0 else None
        if nextData != currentData:
            # data changes here
            if currentData != None:
                out.append((currentStart, evpos-1, currentData))
            currentStart = evpos
            currentData = nextData
    
    return out
```